# How to delete my own message which was mistakenly posted on a friend's timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I mistakenly posted a message on a friend's timeline. I was typing the message and I accidentally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the first letter.

[image]

Now I cannot delete this post. When I hover on the message, nothing happens. No menus or delete signs. Is it forbidden to delete my own messages in the new Facebook?

Comment: If nothing is showing up on your side, can you message your friend and ask him/her to delete it from their end?

Comment: I don't want to do that. Isn't there anything I can directly do?

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar - You made sure it’s not a browser glitch, right? (Logged out/logged back in, cleared browser cache and so on.) Could be the Timeline Review feature?

Comment: @Alex: Yes. I cleared browser cache, cookies, logged out, logged back in, etc. on both IE9 and FF13. That meaningless and annoying message just sits there in front of everyone's eyes.

Comment: You can hover over the post towards the top right corner and an X should appear so that you can delete your post.

Comment: Did you read my question to the end? `When I hover on the message, nothing happens.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your activity log, filter by `Your Posts` and select delete

[image: Delete post]

Or go to see friendship,

`http://www.facebook.com/YOUR_USERNAME_OR_ID?and=FRIEND_USERNAME_OR_ID`

And see if the message is there, click the timestamp you should arrive at

`http://www.facebook.com/FRIEND_USERNAME_OR_ID/posts/POST_ID` and delete the post

[image: Delete post]

If the above fails use this form http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=144040449046092 it's the opposite of what's happening but I don't see why it wouldn't be using the same or around the same feature internally

Comment: I tried the first method you mentioned, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Actions" at the top of the page next to the person's name and the "New message" button.  Go down to "Delete Messages,"  then on the bottom, under your last message posted, there will be a message saying, "Select messages to delete."  Then little empty boxes appear next to each message in the conversation.  You check them then click the delete button next to that last message!